# how to create a jta-data-source file?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jta, glassfish-4.1

I'm using Glassfish 4.1.
Here is how I want my persistence.xml file to be like:

```
<persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="JTA">        
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>PostgreDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have no idea how or where to create the 'PostgreDS' file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to describe your datasource in `glassfish-resources.xml` file and put this file under `webapp/WEB-INF` folder.

Look at this [article](https://stuetzpunkt.wordpress.com/2014/01/06/create-jdbc-resources-on-glassfish-4-with-glassfish-resources-xml/).

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness to mexes_s answer. This is the file I end up for configuring a PostgreSQL connection.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN"
    "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
<jdbc-connection-pool 
        allow-non-component-callers="false" 
        associate-with-thread="false" 
        connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" 
        connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" 
        connection-leak-reclaim="false" 
        connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" 
        connection-validation-method="auto-commit" 
        datasource-classname="org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource" 
        fail-all-connections="false" 
        idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" 
        is-connection-validation-required="false" 
        is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" 
        lazy-connection-association="false" 
        lazy-connection-enlistment="false" 
        match-connections="false" 
        max-connection-usage-count="0" 
        max-pool-size="32" 
        max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" 
        name="java:app/jdbc/PostgreSQLPool" 
        non-transactional-connections="false" 
        pool-resize-quantity="2" 
        res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" 
        statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" 
        steady-pool-size="8" 
        validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" 
        wrap-jdbc-objects="false">    
    <property name="user" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="portNumber" value="5432"/>
    <property name="password" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="databaseName" value="PostgreSQLDB"/>
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/PostgreSQLDB"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource"/>
    <property name="connectionAttributes" value=";create=true"/>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
<jdbc-resource 
        enabled="true" 
        jndi-name="java:app/jdbc/PostgreSQLDS" 
        object-type="user" 
        pool-name="java:app/jdbc/PostgreSQLPool"/>
</resources>
```